# Evaluating trig integral using the complex exponential and Cauchy's residue theorem.

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I am having trouble evaluating the following integral

$$\int_0^\pi \frac{1}{1+sin^2(\theta)} d\theta$$ using the substitution$$z=e^{i\theta} \text{  and   } dz = izd\theta$$.

I know that $$sin\theta = \frac{1}{2i}(z+\frac{1}{z}) \Longrightarrow sin^2\theta = \frac{-1}{4}(z+\frac{1}{z})^2 \Longrightarrow \frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{4}(z+\frac{1}{z})^2}$$
I tried simplifying the denominator by expanding the polynomial and multiplying in the z in from the differential to obtain $$\frac{-4iz}{6z^2-z^4+4}$$ but I can't seem to figure out how to factor it in order to use Cauchy's residue theorem. Any ideas on how to reduce the integrand?

Comment: Are you required to use complex analysis? It would be much easier to rewrite the $1$ in the denominator as $\cos^2(\theta)+\sin^2(\theta)$ and then integrate the antiderivative directly.

Comment: Yes we were told to use the complex substitution to evaluate it

Comment: So use simple element decomposition from your fraction and so you can integrate.